If I am caught and retry do I get more loot?
In the early game after the prologue I have to do my first job which involves infiltrating Pike territory.
This is a stealth section and when caught I have to start over. However I found that the loot was respawned, so I could collect it over again, although it's randomised.
Do I lose any loot I collect before I am caught, or could I potentially farm loot by intentionally getting caught to make more credits?
Having completed the mission in the Pike territory all the loot has gone when you revisit, so I was unable to test this.

I have tested this is another mission, and I collected the loot and then killed myself. Upon respawning I had lost the item I had collected.
So I would assume being Caught trespassing would be a similar thing, you'd lose the items you collected and will have to collect them again.
